# Apache Config: RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) ... NOT match server name?

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat

I'm getting this in error_log when I start Apache:

```
[Tue Mar 09 14:57:02 2010] [notice] mod_python: Creating 4 session mutexes based on 300 max processes and 0 max threads.
[Tue Mar 09 14:57:02 2010] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `*.foo.com' does NOT match server name!?
[Tue Mar 09 14:57:02 2010] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `www.bar.com' does NOT match server name!?
[Tue Mar 09 14:57:02 2010] [notice] Apache configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Child processes then seem to seg fault:

```
[Tue Mar 09 14:57:32 2010] [notice] child pid 3425 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Mar 09 14:57:35 2010] [notice] child pid 3433 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Mar 09 14:57:36 2010] [notice] child pid 3437 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

Server is RHEL, what's going on and what do I need to do to fix this?

**EDIT**
As requested, the dump from httpd -M:

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 mpm_prefork_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 auth_digest_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authn_alias_module (shared)
 authn_anon_module (shared)
 authn_default_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 authz_owner_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_default_module (shared)
 include_module (shared)
 log_config_module (shared)
 logio_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 ext_filter_module (shared)
 mime_magic_module (shared)
 expires_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 usertrack_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 info_module (shared)
 vhost_alias_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 actions_module (shared)
 speling_module (shared)
 userdir_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 cache_module (shared)
 disk_cache_module (shared)
 file_cache_module (shared)
 mem_cache_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 perl_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
 python_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
Syntax OK
```

Comment: It would be useful if you could post the portion of your configuration for that virtual host.  It does seem a bit odd that you get an error for both *.foo.com and www.bar.com.  Do you have 2 certificates setup?

Answer (score 6):

You have two `VirtualHosts`'s configured with different SSL certificates. In every `VirtualHost` you must define `ServerName` parameter, which match `CN` field from SSL certificate.

But `CN` - `ServerName` mismatch shouldn't cause apache to crash. Probably one module has memleak or memory corruption error. Do you have any non standard module loaded into apache? Please, execute `httpd -M` and provide output.

Comment: They have to match to prevent a client error but they don't have to match for Apache to work.

Comment: I updated the question with the output of httpd -m as requested.

Comment: Yes Warner, I know then don't have to match for Apache to work. That's why I wrote that this mismatch shouldn't cause apache to crash.

Comment: I don't see anything non standard. Are you using any external filters (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_ext_filter.html)? Maybe filter child crashes or return some error code? The only idea is to disable unneeded modules and check, if it helps. But your module configuration looks like standard.

Answer (score 0):

The failure to open https websites may be caused by your iptables not opening port 443. This is not related to this error but will cause the website unable to open. Check your iptables to see if it's properly configured.