# Warn: CommonName (CN) `*.xxx.yyy' does NOT match server name?

Tags: apache-2.2

We're getting the occasional error:

```
[warn] RSA server certificate wildcard CommonName (CN) `*.example.com' does NOT match server name!?
```

(This is not a duplicate of [Apache Config: RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) ... NOT match server name?](https://serverfault.com/questions/120889/apache-config-rsa-server-certificate-commonname-cn-not-match-server-name)  read on)

This is non-fatal and is only happening occasionally.

The error is accurate... our cert's CN is doesn't match the VirtualHost.  That's how it's supposed to work.  We match a Subject Alternative Name.

Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: As you said, the error is accurate. It's just a warning.

Comment: It's a bit strange to have it warn me that my config is correct.  It'd be nice to know the cause so that I could suppress the warning.

Answer (score 4):

It's likely that this is caused by the ServerName being set to something other than *.example.com, you could test this by setting the following:

```
ServerName *.example.com
ServerAlias example.com
```

Comment: According the the [docs on ServerName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servername) it has to be an fqdn. It looks like [ServerAlias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias) can have wildcard addresses though.